# How to get the key TAB event on an input element?

Tags: jquery, keyup, keystroke

I try to trigger a button when in an input field the return key has been hit. This works. But if I hit the tab key nothing is triggered because the TAB key event isn't captured.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/a08t4o7r/)

Here is my JQ code snippet for example:

```
$("input[name=input]").on("keypress, keydown, keyup", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ( code == 13 || code == 9 ) {
    $("input[name=btn]").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

I can't figure out how to get the tab key stroke working like a return key stroke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser switching focus on <kbd>Tab</kbd> press.
- Listen for `"keydown"` event only
- Use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead

JavaScript's **which and keyCode are deprecated**, historically they both become a mess.
Even if jQuery normalizes with `jQueryEvent.which` for both `Event.keyCode` and `Event.which` crossbrowser, I think **we should abandon the two** and use the more human friendly **`Event.key`**. What makes more sense, `9` or `'Tab'`? `13` or `'Enter'`? `42` or... what is 42 anyways

```js
$('input[name=input]').on('keydown', function(evt) {
  if (evt.key === 'Tab' || evt.key === 'Enter') {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('input[name=btn]').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Only bind the `keydown` event.
2. `return false` and `preventDefault` on tab key so the focus is not lost.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a08t4o7r/3/

```
$("input[name=input]").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if ( code == 13 || code == 9 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[name=btn]").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` *and* `return false`. Why?`

Comment: Well, it also stops propagation. `returning false` would be enough, but I like having it there, especially in this case (where it's for a submit button and the rest of the function would have to be stopped). The `preventDefault` is there just for code clarity.

Comment: Thank you. This works just fine.  The only thing is that I have to apply a focus change functionality to the function that gets triggered by the button click. If I don't do the user isn't able to change fields with tab.

Comment: If you want to understand more about `preventDefault` and `return false`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: *"returning false would be enough"* you don't understand `return false.`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Take a look at the link I posted.

Comment: Also, you should know that `e.which` is normalized. so no need to `e.keyCode`.