# Select and move focus to specific input field after jQuery.autocomplete() on TAB and/or ENTER

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

**Setup:**

On a html page with three text inputs side by side, 'Text 1' is a jQuery autocomplete as well as 'Text 3', 'Text 2' is just an normal textbox.
as per below screenshot.

[image]

**quest:**

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is that after selection in the last textbox (the 'Text 3', which is a jQuery autocomplete) that the focus shifts back to the 'Text 2' textbox on `[TAB]` press, the behavior should be similar to pressing `[SHIFT] + [TAB]` upon selection in the list of the autocomplete.

**problem:**

This works 'sort of' on 'Text 1' primarily because focus would move to 'Text2' anyway. To move correctly on `[Enter]` I have captured the `event.keypress==13` on the select event of the autocomplete. 
In 'Text 1' the top value gets selected and focus shifts to 'Text 2' if I press either `[Enter]` or `[TAB]` which is the correct behavior.

```
$("#Text1").autocomplete({
    source: someArray,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 50,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#Text1').data('someid', ui.item.uKey);

        //Ensure move to next field on [Enter]
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#Text2').focus();
        }
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
    }
});
```

This capturing does not seem to work in case of the `TAB` key. 
If I amend the `select` event of the autocomplete I can capture the keypress event, but if I request the same behavior it doesn't work.

```
...
//amended select statement
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#Text1').data('someid', ui.item.uKey);

    //Try capture [TAB] and move to next field on [TAB] keypress ** doesn't work ! **
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        $('#Text2').focus(); //focus doesn't move, though Text1 loses it...
    }

    //Ensure move to next field on [Enter]
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#Text2').focus();
    }
},
```

If I try to control the behavior of the `[TAB]` key on the keypress event of the 'Text 3' textbox I get no control whatsoever. On `[Enter]` no problems, correct redirection, but not on `[TAB]`.

I've tried capturing the keypress event on the textbox (outside the autocomplete) this does capture the keypress event but also doesn't move the focus to 'Text 2'.

I've tried `event.preventDefault();` and  `stopPropagation();` on the `[TAB]` press event of 'Text 3' but that indeed just stops any propagation, moreover; the autocomplete will not select if you do that...

```
$('#Text3').keypress(function(event){
   if (event.keyCode==9){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('#Text2').focus();
   }
});
```

So, how to select the top item **AND** redirect focus to any desired field on the autocomplete on `[TAB]` press event ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of below question
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084191/jquery-how-to-get-the-key-tab-event-on-an-input-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084191/jquery-how-to-get-the-key-tab-event-on-an-input-element)

Comment: Unfortunately, no it isn't a duplicate. I know how to capture a TAB key, and to handle the process thereafter. It's specifically about the combination with jQuery autocomplete.

Comment: If you can create a fiddle then i can work it out.